# Add Date in Oracle Table for TimeStamp Column using c#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have written Code to add the Date to oracle table with column of type 'TimeStamp'
but i am getting the error of

> 'ORA-01843: not a valid month',  my code is below, column in oracle DB
>   of type 'Timestamp', trying to update the column with c#,

```
DateTime dt = 
        DateTime.Parse(Convert.ToString(CurrentItem[SharePointColumnInternal[j]]));
        dt = dt.ToLocalTime();
        UpdateCmd += i + "=" + "'" + dt + "'" + ",";
```

This is the update command string that I have built :UpdateCmd 
and executing in the c# code.

Comment: DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(Convert.ToString("11/18/2019 10:24AM");
                                    dt = dt.ToLocalTime();

Comment: I am trying to add above date in oracle timestamp column using c#,

Comment: Please help me to format the Date in correct format,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be building your SQL commands by concatenating strings; this is not only more difficult, but also open to SQL injection.

Have a look at using parameterised queries, for example:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(Convert.ToString(CurrentItem[SharePointColumnInternal[j]]));
dt = dt.ToLocalTime();

using (var connection = new OracleConnection("YourConnectionString"))
using (var command = new OracleCommand("UPDATE YourTable SET YourDateTimeColumn = :dt Where ...", connection))
{
    command.Parameters.Add("dt", dt);
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: Thanks its working for me, after changing inline query into parameter.